# SSD with much lower space and extra partitions

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, ssd

So I used a cloning software(EaseUS Todo Backup Free) to clone windows from my old HDD to my new SSD and now I have two new partition in my 250GB SSD that each take around 64GB and I'm left with total 66GB free space in my new fresh SSD and can't do anything anymore.

[image: http://imgur.com/a/VYlZy]

In Disk Management, I can right click on the "System reserved" and there is a delete option, the first unnamed one doesn't even have that...
Any idea what to do or why this is happening? Cause I can't even do anything on this now

Thank you in advance

Comment: use 3rd party partition tool to resize partitions.

Comment: It appears your disk cloning tool simply resized all partitions proportionally. You may have selected an inappropriate option.